# Determine the probability densities for coefficients of equation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

> Both roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ of a square equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ can take any value from $-1$ to $1$  with equal probability . Determine the probability densities for coefficients $a$ and $b$.

I think I should use the properties of Vieta's theorem then $x_1+x_2=-a$ and $x_1\cdot x_2=b$.

And I don't know how to solve it further.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Any value in $[-1,1]$ or in $\{-1,1\}$? In the first case we actually do not know the distribution, but only that it has continuous distribution.

Comment: @drhab the first case

Comment: Then this cannot be solved. Don't you mean to say that $x_1,x_2$ have *uniform distribution* on $[-1,1]$ (and are independent as well, I think)?

Comment: @drhab If it's not specified explicitly in the problem statement, then obviously it is assumed.

Comment: @drhab it's not stated in the statement, maybe it's really supposed to be

Comment: @drhab so do you have any ideas about this issue?)

Comment: @peter.petrov  so do you have any ideas about this issue?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of two $U(0,\,1)$ IIDs has an [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) of PDF $1-|1-x|$ on $[0,\,2]$. Linearly transforming, we get the PDF of the sum of two $U(-1,\,1)$ IIDs, which here we take to be the $-x_i$: $a$ has PDF $\frac12(1-|a|)$ on $[-2,\,2]$.

We use the roots' distributions' symmetry to address the other coefficient. Since each $-\ln|x_i|\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$, $\ell:=-\ln|b|\sim\Gamma(2,\,1)$ has PDF $\ell\exp-\ell$ on $[0,\,\infty)$, i.e. $b$ has the even PDF $-\frac12\ln|b|$ on $[-1,\,1]$.